# Is there a regex pattern to extract values inbetween quote marks when there may be a quote mark in the quote

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex pattern to extract an element from the below structures:

```
Video 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/arjun-sofat-2990939b' rendered
Video 'Pennythornes's Bar - NW9 8LU' rendered
```

I am looking to extract the elements for the unique name.

So the general structure would be

```
Video 'EXTRACTHERE' rendered
```

For the two examples given above the regex should make the extractions go to

```
https://www.linkedin.com/in/arjun-sofat-2990939b'
Pennythornes's Bar - NW9 8LU
```

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this regexp.

```
/Video ['"](.*)['"] rendered/g
```